# working with CursorAdapter

Tags: android

This is my cursor adapter class. I set this adapter to a listview. I also did notifydatasethanged(). But still i m not getting any result i.e. when item is added, list view still shows blank

```
public class tasksCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public tasksCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView tvTask, tvDate, tvTime;
    tvTask = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_added);
    tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_added);
    tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_added);
    tvTask.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    tvDate.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    tvTime.setText(cursor.getString(3));

}
}
```

Comment: Is that your whole adapter? Where is the getCount method? Where is your getView method?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add getCount method you will not see views being added to the list view